# Set output file name for PDF exporter

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports 5.6*
I generate pdf using PDFCreator.
My pdf is generated successfully, but i can't set name to that PDF file.

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("PDFCreator", null));   
JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter(); 
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(tempFileName));
SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(printRequestAttributeSet);
configuration.setPrintServiceAttributeSet(printServiceAttributeSet);
configuration.setDisplayPageDialog(false);
configuration.setDisplayPrintDialog(false);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);   
exporter.exportReport();
```

My pdf name are set using that PDFCreator tool
I want to pass the name to that pdf file.
Since   `exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "d:/adc.pdf");` method is now deprecated.
Please tell me solution how to set that out file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to pass a file name to PDFCreator, because the whole idea is that it is a virtual printer. So to the program that sending the document, it could be being printed on a physical printer somewhere, hence an output file name would be irrelevant.

Whenever I need to output reports as PDFs I use `JasperExportManager`, which is a much simpler solution. The `exportReportToPdfFile` method accepts the output file path as a string. Example:

```
JasperPrint filledReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport("report.jrxml", params);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(filledReport, "report.pdf");
```

Alternatively, you can keep your code largely the same but change your `JRPrintServiceExporter` to a [`JRPdfExporter`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPdfExporter.html). The new way to set the output format (now that `setParameter` is deprecated) is to construct an [`ExporterOutput`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export]) and then call [`setExporterOutput`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRAbstractExporter.html#setExporterOutput%28O%29/ExporterOutput.html) on your exporter.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But Sir initially we are facing problem to read regional language in jasper report. we choose to use above code.**JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile** will export pdf but for regional language it will showing blank data.

Comment: @Vicky3D I might not the best person to deal with locale issues, and it would also be difficult to do so in the comments here. You should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the problem so that it gets a wider audience and you can include more details.